# Customize an Archer Application from an external Application

Tags: archer

I would like to make a desktop application (C#) that can create a custom Archer application and modify one of my current Archer applications (and subforms). I checked the SOAP and REST API but they have no functions for this purpose.

I was wondering if this is possible, and if it is, then can you help me get in the right direction to solve this?

is there a way to automate the creation of a custom archer application?

i've been thinking about creating this custom apps adding directly their info in the archer database. Nevertheless, i don't know if this could be a good way, since the archer database is complex and i haven't found any documentation about it.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hey, can you please send me a message and share the use case of why would you need something like this? are you trying to implement your own code version control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are going to struggle to get any support from RSA for doing this. It is possible to reverse engineer the database to make changes but you would be working without any documentation and would be vulnerable to any system updates changing the way the data is stored as RSA release new updates.

You could look at reverse engineering the packaging and have your desktop application output packages that could be installed. This limits your impact in making direct database changes but is still not advisable.

Sorry I can't offer more help to a fellow Archer hacker, good luck!

Comment: I already did exactly what you said, i set all my changes and then exported the package. Then i set an initial state for the Archer instance, and took a snapshot at the DB. Then i installed the package and took another snapshot. With those two snapshots i compared with visual studio the differences between the two databases and generated the script. Then the tricky part is to clean up the script. There are a lot of records that doesn't belong to your changes. Once that is sorted, and some extra code to control IDs, you are ready to go. The application is working now, for 5.5 and 6.1. Thanks.